# Authorizer context not passed in event to AWS lambda function when using AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-authorizer

I'm working on setting up an AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) template for an API Gateway with a request-based authorizer. I have a lambda function which is connected to a API Gateway which has a authorizer. My template looks like this.

```
ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
      AuthorizerUri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${APIGatewayAuthFunction.Arn}/invocations
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      Name: ApiGatewayAuthorizer
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiWithAuthorizer
      Type: REQUEST

# this is API with authorizer
ApiWithAuthorizer:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Dev
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Type: REGIONAL
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: ApiGatewayAuthorizer

ApiGatewayAuthorizerInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt APIGatewayAuthFunction.Arn
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com

APIGatewayAuthFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Timeout: 600
    CodeUri: authorizer/
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.11
    FunctionName: APIGatewayAuthFunction

MyAPILambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
  Properties:
    Timeout: 600
    CodeUri: hello/
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.11
    FunctionName: MyAPILambdaFunction
    Role: !GetAtt ApiGatewayLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Layers:
      - !Ref MyApiSharedLayer
    Events:
      InventoryListApi:
        Type: Api 
        Properties:
          RestApiId: !Ref ApiWithAuthorizer
          Path: /hello
          Method: get
```

My Authorizer function returns following response when valid.

```
{
    "principalId": "yyyyy",  
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "ARN of the method",
            }
        ],
    },
    "context": {"custom_key": "custom_value"},
}
```

But when I test the Authorizer or send a request to hello api I am not able to get context in its event even though authorization is successfull.

```
event.get("requestContext", {}).get("authorizer", {}).get("custom_key", None)
```

Seems like context is not passed when using AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer.

Is there any other configuration I am missing out on?